# Recommended example applications written in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Which recent, public, medium-sized Ember.js applications do you recommend for learning about usage patterns by reading its implementations?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd recommend the **[Travis CI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci)** project - it uses Ember on the client side and Rail 3 on the server.  While it doesn't use the latest Ember features it has very good foundations.  You'll find the client-side code in a separate repo [travis-web](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web).

I also found reading through **@ebryn's "[New Twitter](https://github.com/ebryn/newtwitter)"** helpful although it is older (Sproutcore 2) and smaller/simpler than Travis CI.

**Update:** Ember has gone through a number of big changes leading up to their 1.0 release so a lot of older example apps use deprecated APIs and are no longer representative of best practices.  A new example to check out is **Discourse** (https://github.com/discourse/discourse) a large webapp built by Jeff Atwood and Robin Ward.  Also, check out @trek's **Ember Todos**, a version of **TodoMVC** with a touch more process (https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences)

Comment: Discourse is a great app to look at Ember features, however, their codebase uses lot of the old features in emberjs. But they do work perfectly

Comment: For Emberjs & Laravel learners, [Exyht](http://exyht.github.io/exyht) could be a good example.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend the ToDoMVC project, which offers the same Todo application implemented using MV* concepts in most of the popular JavaScript MV* frameworks of today. Now ToDO MVC ember.js example adapts ember.js 1.0.rc1.
The website: http://todomvc.com/
The source: https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc

Answer (score 4):

[Emberwatch](http://emberwatch.com/) has an [Open Source Category](http://emberwatch.com/open_source.html) with a list of interesting projects.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1 great to start with authentication.

And also it from smashing magazine http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/

a good exercise is to put those apps to work in http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/ that has the current releases